# How to code "A2" to add to end of combobox in userform?

Tags: combobox, userform

I have a userform that the user can input data regarding solar panels and it fills in sheet1. I am now trying to allow the user to input new data that will go to the end of the combobox in the userform. So for example, if they start using a new manufacterur, they can just type in the name of the manufacturer somewhere (right now in sheet 2) and I need to code it so it will end up at the end of the Manufacturer combobox in the userform. What is the most effective way to do this and how do I code it. The solution I'm looking for would be the user clicks on sheet 2, types in the new manufacturer, presses add, and it pops up at the end of the manufacturer combobox in the userform (userform1). Thanks.

sheet 1
userform

Comment: I cant upload a pic of sheet 2 for some reason. It looks like: In A1 "New Manufacturer", A2-where the user types the new manufacturers name, and then a combobox captioned "add" below

Comment: You should show as much as you can in the question as text. Also, where is your [mcve]?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this site and have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Then take the [tour] and read [ask] and most will be made clear. But you aren't going to get much interest unless you show what you have tried, and provide some examples of what you have tried.